# For a (left) ideal $I$, how can $R \cdot I$ be a proper subset?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have the following definition for a left ideal: An additive subgroup $I$ of a ring $R$ is called left ideal, if $R \cdot I \subseteq I$ where $R \cdot I = \{ r \cdot i \,\,\,|\,\,\, r \in R, i \in I\}$.

My question is: how can $R \cdot I$ be a proper subset of $I$? My first observation is that if this is indeed the case, $R$ isn't allowed to have a neutral element for multiplication, because else $R \cdot I \supseteq 1 \cdot I = I \Rightarrow R=I$.

Is there an easy example?

Comment: why do you need $R \cdot I$ is a proper subset of $I$? the given definition said $R \cdot I \subseteq I,$ **not** $R \cdot I \subsetneq I.$

Comment: I don't need it, but if it wasn't possible, wouldn't the definition simply require that $R\cdot I = I$ instead of $R \cdot I \subseteq I$?

Comment: As a complete aside, if you want to make a larger space in LaTeX you can use \quad.

Comment: @marc asking for equality is excessive. It will happen for rings with identity, but you'll be stuck for rings without identity.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Slugger! This has annoyed me for quite some time but not enough to search for a solution / ask a question :) Test "quad": $\{x \in \mathbb{R} \quad|\quad x^2=1\}$ Hmm, doesn't really look nice. Test "mid": $\{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x^2=1\}$ What I had before: $\{x \in \mathbb{R} | x^2=1\}$

Comment: @Marc I think you'd rather use \mid instead of trying to get the spacing nice.  As in $\{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x^2=1\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $R = 2\mathbb Z, I = 8 \mathbb Z.$ Then $8 \notin R \cdot I.$

Comment: Is this $R$ a ring?

Comment: @KittyL: If you insist that a ring must contain multiplicative identity then it's not. Otherwise it's  a ring. But as OP already observed that if such an example exists, then the ring must not contain the multiplicative identity. So we can *safely* assume (in this context) that a ring need not have to have multiplicative identity.

Comment: Thanks for both the example and for mentioning that there are different conventions!